# How to tell which driver is being used by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have "inherited" a computer that has multiple ODBC driver's installed on it. Before I go removing anything, how do I tell which driver SQL Server is actually using? Does it just use the most updated one?

[image: List of drivers installed]

I am running SQL Server 2014, version 12.0.5207.0 (64 bit). I am also using SQL Server Management Studio 2017, version 17.5.

Additional question - I am planning to update the ODBC driver to 13.1, would I install the 64 bit since the server is 64 bit? When I look at the ODBC data sources the drivers are installed in both the 32-bit and 64-bit dialogues, so I am a bit confused. Total noob question, I realize, but I am very new to this.

Comment: Just posted some thoughts, see if it's of any help.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an easy answer. Let's break it into parts.

What driver is being used? The one the application requests. A driver is used by a client application to connect to the server, and the client application is the one that has the final say. You can look at the ODBC data sources configured in the machine to see the driver, but an application might not use an ODBC data source and instead embed the driver name into the application or some configuration file.

How can you tell? One way is to uninstall a driver and see what breaks. Usually not a good plan. Maybe you can use Process Monitor and check if any process load the drivers, but not Always feasible. If in doubt, leave the drivers alone. They are usually small and don't tend to cause trouble on their own.

As for SQL Server database engine and SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), they normally don't use ODBC drivers. SSMS uses a .NET provider to connect to SQL Server. SQL Server database engine can use an ODBC driver if you have a linked server to another server.

If this is a database server and not an application server, chances are most drivers are rarelly used. If this is an application server, I'd leave the drivers alone. If it's a workstation, probably leave them alone too.

As for the new driver version, you need the 64-bit package to install, and it will install both 32 and 64-bit drivers. The reason is a 32-bit need a 32-bit driver, and a 64-bit application need a 64-bit driver. It's not the server bitness that matter in this case.

Comment: Helpful response, thank you. I'll leave the drivers alone!

Comment: Worth noting the server can have a dependency on clients drivers if there are linked servers/dts jobs/replication etc.

Comment: Linked servers are noted in the response. DTS/SSIS are a good remember.